# Django - Authentication - redirect

Tags: django

I'm using Django standard auth. / login having the following loc in my /urls.py.

```
(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'home.html', }),
```

Login works fine if the user calls www.myapp.com and login redirects to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/pm/po/my/' (www.myapp.com/pm/po/my/) defined in the settings.py.

The session is not killed (= user is not logged out) if the user closes the browser tab, leaving open the browser. Which is also fine.

However if the user then opens a new tab and goes to www.myapp.com the login view is shown again, while being the user already logged in. Here I want the user have redirected to www.myapp.com/pm/po/my/ .

How can I achieve this?

I tried it adding the following line:

```
(r'^$', 'myapp.project_management.views.projects'),
(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'home.html', }),
```

However this leads to the following error message: "This webpage has a redirect loop"

--Solution--

urls.py:

```
(r'^$', 'myapp.project_management.views.my_projects'),
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'home.html', }),
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make the home URL point to the login page. Instead, use the [`login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/contrib/auth/decorators/) to redirect non-logged in users to the login page as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own view for login url, and make redirect if your user login ( usually with  request.method = 'POST'), or this user already have authorized.